# Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/webpack/utils/helpers'

Tags: ionic-framework

`./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/jit-polyfills.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es7/reflect' in '\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models'`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this command solved it:

```
install git+https://github.com/angular/angular-devkit-build-angular-builds.git
```